# Show user favourite tags for quick access on Stack Overflow mobile app

Tags: feature-request, tags, stack-overflow-app

I find it annoying to type every time I go to the app for favorite tags. If we have favorite tags then only questions related to them should be shown on home activity and they should be one click away.

For example, there is no reason to show C# related questions to a user who only knows PHP.

Comment: They're trying to drop you a hint...

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Overflow mobile app had [one of the the worst receptions in the history of Meta](/q/349255/6388243) because a large portion of the features that seasoned users loved were completely absent.

At the same time, [the Stack *Exchange* mobile app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8) had been around for a lot longer and could already do Stack Overflow, rendering it mostly superfluous.

There's a link in the footer to the mobile site that actually has a lot of the site's features on it. Use that (or even the regular site) instead.

Comment: I actually have both...:rofl: but this feature is also missing from SE app too.

Comment: @darkknight I use typically the mobile version of the site on phones and the full on tablets. I think the apps still need some development to switch to them.